# Putting require 'spec_helper' results in Bad URI error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I did rails generate rspec:install, 
ran rake spec and it works just fine.

However, when I create a new spec file and add require 'spec_helper', I get the following error.

```
rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:176:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?):  (URI::InvalidURIError)
```

Anyone know what might be the issue?

EDIT: Also, when I run rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test I get

```
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?):
```

Maybe, this has something to do with Raven for Sentry?

Answer (score 0):

Raven dependency was causing this issue.